# how to change Id of textbox inside a cloned div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  with textbox , on cloning it ,I am able to change id of div but unable to change id of textbox inside div..

```js
    var toAddCloneCount = 0;
    function AddDestination() {
        var clone = $("#toAdd").clone(true);
        clone.find('textbox').attr('id', 'days' + toAddCloneCount);
        clone.show();
        clone.attr('id', 'toAdd' + toAddCloneCount++).insertAfter("#toAdd");
        clone.appendTo("#destinations");
 }
```

Comment: show your ` #toAdd`  html element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
clone.find('#toAdd').prop('id', 'days' + toAddCloneCount);
```

Comment: and how to change id of <asp:DropDownList ID="toCity" on cloning?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadYasir when asp control render they also render as html no diffrence

Answer (score 3):

`textbox` is not a valid html element.  Did you mean `textarea`?   Or maybe `input[type=text]`?   You should be using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) if you are using jQuery 1.6+

Try

```
clone.find('textarea').prop('id', 'days' + toAddCloneCount);
```

OR

```
clone.find('input[type=text]').prop('id', 'days' + toAddCloneCount);
```

Comment: and how to change id of  <asp:DropDownList ID="toCity"  on cloning?